# pip install /tmp/pip-c436mD-unpack/master the member espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs/social is invalid:

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, bulbs

I am trying to instally bulbs on my Ubuntu 12.04.I have installed the following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

I have installed

```
 sudo pip install  https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master
```

The output is as follows

```
Downloading/unpacking https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master
  Downloading master (unknown size): 177Kb downloaded
  Cannot determine compression type for file /tmp/pip-c436mD-unpack/master
  In the tar file /tmp/pip-c436mD-unpack/master the member espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs/social is invalid: "linkname 'espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs//home/james/projects/bulbflow.com/www/root/templates/social.html' not found"
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '.'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '.'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/old'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/old'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2>=0.7.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml>=3.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.11-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): omnijson in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omnijson-0.1.2-py2.7.egg (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil==1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Cleaning up...
```

Is the line

```
In the tar file /tmp/pip-c436mD-unpack/master the member espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs/social is invalid: "linkname 'espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs//home/james/projects/bulbflow.com/www/root/templates/social.html' not found"
```

displayed above an error ? And does it mean that the install of bulbs has not succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about that message -- that's not an error -- from the output above, it looks like Bulbs is installed. Start up Rexster and and then try it out...

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> james = g.vertices.create(name="James")
>>> julie = g.vertices.create(name="Julie")
>>> g.edges.create(james, "knows", julie)
```